# Plugin that Concatenates Contact and Account Name on create of an Account record

Tags: c#, visual-studio, plugins, crm

I am not familiar with plugins and with C# and I need to create a plugin that Concatenates the text value of a Contact and Account Name on create of an Account record. Ex: ABC Company" - John Smith"  I am using Visual Studio and CRM 2016 Online(trial). Here is what I have so far:

using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using System;

namespace CRMPluginProject4
{
    public class ConcatPlugin : IPlugin
    {
        #region Secure/Unsecure Configuration Setup
        private string _secureConfig = null;
        private string _unsecureConfig = null;

```
    public ConcatPlugin(string unsecureConfig, string secureConfig)
    {
        _secureConfig = secureConfig;
        _unsecureConfig = unsecureConfig;
    }
    #endregion
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        ITracingService tracer = (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));
        IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
        IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

        try
        {
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

            //TODO: Do stuff




      }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

PJM, You can do this using java script instead of writing a plugin to do the same.

Still if you want to go with a plugin, please use the code as follows,

```
if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
                    {
                        //Get the target property and check whether its a contact.
                        Entity target = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                        string primaryContactId = target.Attributes.Contains("primarycontactid") ? ((EntityReference)target.Attributes["primarycontactid"]).Name : string.Empty;
                        string accountName = target.Attributes.Contains("name") ? target.Attributes["name"].ToString() : string.Empty;
                        target["name"] = accountName + "-" + primaryContactId;

                    }
```

Please make sure this is dont in the pre operation of create and update of account. Hope this helps you. Let us know if you need any more help.

Comment: Great! Thank you! Also, when I try to run the plugin in Visual Studio I receive an error that says: "A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly. In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project" What does this mean? @Renjith

Comment: Class libraries are normally used as reusable references to other applications so it cant stand alone and work. You have to refer the library to another project like a console, website, windows and so on. But the same can be registered as a plugin in CRM and tagged to any event and can be used. 

Make sure you are inheriting IPlugin to the class so that it can be accessed and used in CRM. Assume you have already done that.